# Creating a Number Line Continuum

Tags: plotting

In Wolfram, how can one create a plot similar to the following:

[image]

That is: a number-line like continuum with labeled points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[77]
lst = RandomSample[Range[-10, 10, .25], 5];

ListPlot[MapThread[{Callout[#, Rotate[#[[1]], 90 Degree], Above, 
          LeaderSize -> 30, LabelStyle -> Directive[#2, 12], 
          CalloutMarker -> "Arrow", "CalloutStyle" -> #2]} &,
     {Thread[{lst, 0}], ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@lst]}], 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[.015], Axes -> {True, False}, 
   Ticks -> {Range[-10, 10], None}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, Automatic},
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1],
   AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{{-.05, 0}, {.05, 1}}]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Using custom `Arrowheads` to label the two directions of horizontal axis:

```
ListPlot[MapThread[{Callout[#, Rotate[#[[1]], 90 Degree], Above, 
     LeaderSize -> 30, LabelStyle -> Directive[#2, 12], 
     CalloutMarker -> "Arrow", "CalloutStyle" -> #2]} &,
   {Thread[{lst, 0}], ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@lst]}], 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[.015], Axes -> {True, False}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[-10, 10], None}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, Automatic},
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{{-.05, 0}, {.05, 1},
     {.05, 0,  Graphics @ Text[Style["negative direction", 16], {0, 0}, {1., 0}]}, 
     {.05, 1, Graphics @ Text[Style["positive direction", 16], {0, 0}, {-1.1, 0}]}}], 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
  ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[.15], Scaled[.15]}, {None, Scaled[.05]}}, 
  ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

Alternatively, add the axes labels using `Epilog`:

```
ListPlot[MapThread[{Callout[#, Rotate[#[[1]], 90 Degree], Above, 
     LeaderSize -> 30, LabelStyle -> Directive[#2, 12], 
     CalloutMarker -> "Arrow", "CalloutStyle" -> #2]} &, 
    {Thread[{lst,  0}], ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@lst]}], 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[.015], Axes -> {True, False}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[-10, 10], None}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, Automatic},
  AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{{-.05, 0}, {.05, 1}}], 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
  ImagePadding -> {{Scaled[.2], Scaled[.2]}, {None, Scaled[.05]}}, 
  ImageSize -> 700, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["negative direction", 16], Offset[{-30, 0}, {-11, 0}], {1, 0}] , 
   Text[Style["positive direction", 16], Offset[{30, 0}, {11, 0}], {-1, 0}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to label the arrow heads on both side of the plot (i.e., the left one "negative direction" and the right one perhaps "positive direction")?

Comment: @George, please see the update.

Comment: The second method (using `Epilog`) doesn't work on my local version of Wolfram Desktop (I just see the number line w/o any text). Is this also the case on your machine?

Comment: @George, I don't have the desktop version of v12. The pictures I posted are obtained using v12 on Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: [This](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/user-900a994f-78ab-4931-b18e-353eff4d0b33/375521432816174362116122552088693507915062801467.png) is what I"m seeing.